# LVM partitioning - how to assign disk space equally

Tags: partitioning, disk, lvm, storage

I want to divide the remaining space on an LVM physical volume exactly equally between five new logical volumes (they're going to end up as personal network drives for five users).

Is there a best-practice way of creating the logical volumes so that they all get exactly the same portion of the space remaining in the physical volume?

Thanks

Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no special tool or parameter for that. You probably should not do that, anyway.

You should leave some unused space on your volumegroup, so that you can grow your logical volumes in case of an emergency (space runni.ng out on your / partition if you install updates, space running out on database, etc.)

You also want free space on your volumegroup for lvm snapshots.

Growing of logical volumes is easy and fast and you can do it in production, shrinking volumes is harder and riscier so always keep some space in reserve.

Comment: Ok - thank you for the advice. I'll leave some empty space on the volume group.